# Python and SQlite delete a row with more than one argument

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to delete a row but I must consider more than one argument to it.

To delete a row with an argument this is the code:

```
def delete_row(title): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('eventosUTN.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_update_query = """DELETE from eventos WHERE title = ?"""
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, (title, ))
    conn.commit()
```

So, To delete a row with two arguments I did:

```
def delete_row(title, date): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect('eventosUTN.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_update_query = """DELETE from eventos WHERE title = ? AND WHERE date=?"""
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, (title, date))
    conn.commit()
```

But it does not work. What I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the sql statement to
`DELETE from eventos WHERE title = ? AND date=?`. A single `where` followed by multiple arguments

Comment: It does not work. The problem is in cursor.execute function

Comment: Yes, that's because you have the query syntax wrong. cursor.execute sends the query for execution and receives the response. If the query syntax is wrong then it will throw an exception @JuliánOviedo